# Keras on Google ML Engine error: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, google-cloud-ml

I have deployed a model on Google Cloud ML Engine, but when I try to perform a prediction (I'm using curl), this is the result I obtain:

`{"error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'lstm_1/keras_learning_phase' with dtype bool\n\t [[Node: lstm_1/keras_learning_phase = Placeholder[dtype=DT_BOOL, shape=[], _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"]()]]\")"}`

How exactly can I set the value of this placeholder tensor? Is it on the json? Is it something that has to be done during training? As many suggestions said, I tried setting `K.set_learning_phase(0)` but didnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Let me guess - your model has batch normalization layers, right? :)

> As many suggestions said, I tried setting `K.set_learning_phase(0)` but didnt work.

Indeed - I happened to have the same problem a couple of days ago; the solution is to set

```
K.set_learning_phase(0)
```

**before** initializing (or loading) your model - if you do it later in the script, the said error keeps poping up...

Comment: So, do you mean during training, right? I'll try it and report my results. My "quick fix" was removing dropout from my layer. Thanks

Comment: @user3276768 I mean during *inference* (otherwise, your `keras_learning_phase` should be 1, not 0).

Comment: As far as I understand, you can't modify the way Google ML Engine perform the predictions. It is a service, in which you just upload the saved model and it does the rest for you. So it is not possible for me to modify underlying code.

Comment: @user3276768 so, how did you set `K.set_learning_phase(0)`, as you say in your post?

Comment: I set it in the training script, which apparently is wrong.

Comment: Can you set the flag before exporting the saved model?